# SELECT *FROM UMTS_new WHERE Drop_Speech_Rate>1 не отрабатывает sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

SELECT *FROM UMTS_new WHERE Drop_Speech_Rate>1
Почему то, условие явное задаю, чтоб было показан список больше значения 0. Но почему то меньше 0 так же выводит система[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь!

Comment: У вас там строки небось.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что значения в строчках имеют привязку к типу
(англ.
«[*type affinity*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)»)
`TEXT`. Чтобы перевести в `REAL`, надо
заменить запятые на точки и сконвертировать:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM umts_new
 WHERE CAST(REPLACE(drop_speech_rate, ',', '.') AS REAL) > 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!